# Yii2: How to use JavaScript functions like onchange() in a view

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2, onchange

I have a a **checkbox**:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <?= Html::checkbox('chocolate', false) ?>
        Chocolate
    </label>
</div>
```

Also I have a **span** tag:

```
<span>I like all chocolates.</span>
```

I want to use the **onchange** JavaScript function or jQuery (I am beginner using jQuery) to show the span if the user check the checkbox.

First I need to get the value of `chocolate`. But it is not JavaScript code, it is PHP code: `<?= Html::checkbox('chocolate', false) ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add a class to your span. After, you can add a change event handler to your checkbox in order to toggle the display style: from none to block.

In order to add the script to your view, you may add the script itself at the bottom of your view in the **script** tags:

```
 <script>
    document.querySelector('.checkbox [type="checkbox"][name="chocolate"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        console.log(this.checked);
        document.querySelector('span.chocoLike').style.display = (this.checked) ? 'block' : 'none';
    })
</script>
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    document.querySelector('.checkbox [type="checkbox"][name="chocolate"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        console.log(this.checked);
        document.querySelector('span.chocoLike').style.display = (this.checked) ? 'block' : 'none';
    })
})
```

```css
.chocoLike {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chocolate">
        Chocolate
    </label>
</div>
<span class="chocoLike">I like all chocolates.</span>
```